# Windows system files hash database

Tags: windows, hash, system

Is there a database of windows xp/Vista/7/8 system files like csrss.exe and audiodg.exe? I know that there is a default programm which can check system files from being corrupted, but is there a database of hashes like md5 or crc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [NIST National Software Reference Library](http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/Diskprints.htm). The "Software Diskprints" may be helpful to you.